# Build JSON from DB result PHP

Tags: php, json

I have a table rows as follows,

enter image description here[DB returns rows looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNLfJ.png)

From the above result, i have to build the JSON like below,

If user select grouping by columns like "TARGETDATE" followed by "ASSIGNEE" followed by "SUBCATEGORY" from the user interface, then i want to prepare json like below

```
[
{
    "key": "21-AUG-20",
    "items": [
      {
        "key": "VINAY",
        "items": [
          {
            "key": "FEATURE",
            "items": null,
            "count": 1,
            "summary": []
          }],
        "count": 1,
        "summary": []
      }],
    "count": 1,
    "summary": []
},
{
    "key": "22-AUG-20",
    "items": [
      {
        "key": "ASHWIN",
        "items": [
          {
            "key": "Bug",
            "items": null,
            "count": 1,
            "summary": []
          }],
        "count": 1,
        "summary": []
      },
      {
        "key": "DIVYA",
        "items": [
          {
            "key": "TEST",
            "items": null,
            "count": 1,
            "summary": []
          }],
        "count": 1,
        "summary": []
      }
      ],
    "count": 2,
    "summary": []
},
{
    "key": "25-AUG-20",
    "items": [
      {
        "key": "VINAY",
        "items": [
          {
            "key": "LIVE",
            "items": null,
            "count": 1,
            "summary": []
          }],
        "count": 1,
        "summary": []
      }],
    "count": 1,
    "summary": []
}
]
```

If user select grouping by columns like "TARGETDATE" followed by "ASSIGNEE" from the user interface, then i want to build json like below

```
[
{
    "key": "21-AUG-20",
    "items": [
      {
        "key": "VINAY",
        "items": [],
        "count": 1,
        "summary": []
      }],
    "count": 1,
    "summary": []
},
{
    "key": "22-AUG-20",
    "items": [
      {
        "key": "ASHWIN",
        "items": [],
        "count": 1,
        "summary": []
      },
      {
        "key": "DIVYA",
        "items": [],
        "count": 1,
        "summary": []
      }
      ],
    "count": 2,
    "summary": []
},
{
    "key": "25-AUG-20",
    "items": [
      {
        "key": "VINAY",
        "items": [],
        "count": 1,
        "summary": []
      }],
    "count": 1,
    "summary": []
}
]
```

Here the user has flexibility to group by 1 to N columns, I have tried code for group by single column which is quite simple task,

Code I tried

```
if(isset($rowsArr[$tRow["TARGETDATE"]])){ 
    $rowsArr[$tRow["TARGETDATE"]] = $rowsArr[$tRow["TARGETDATE"]] + 1; 
}else{ 
    $rowsArr[$tRow["TARGETDATE"]] = 1; 
} 
$filteredResult = array(); 
foreach($rowsArr as $key => $val){ 
    $temp = array(); 
    $temp["key"] = $key; 
    $temp["items"] = null; 
    $temp["count"] = $val; 
    $temp["summary"] = null; 
    array_push($filteredResult,$temp); 
}
```

Did it only when group by is done for one column (TARGETDATE). How to build the json structure when group by multiple columns?.

Comment: If the user wants to group by column X, Y, Z then you should build your PHP array like `$result[X][Y][Z] = value` and then simply `json_encode` it.

Comment: I do not want to loop it multiple times, please have a look at required json again. It has count attribute as well which will track of how many available sub groups

Comment: If it is easier for you - you can generate your JSON with SQL. Latest versions of both MySQL and PostgreSQL support JSON.

Comment: I'm using Oracle 11g @IVO GELOV